# Creating a Laravel project, got an error: no configuration file provided: not found

Tags: laravel, docker, project

I am creating a new Laravel project in MAC M1.
I create the project: `curl -s "https://laravel.build/devstagram" | bash`

but when I want to do sail up: `./vendor/bin/sail up` I got this error: **no configuration file provided: not found**

I already tried:

```
php artisan sail:install

bash ./vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail up
```

My docker version:

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:01:18 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 17:59:41 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.10
  GitCommit:        770bd0108c32f3fb5c73ae1264f7e503fe7b2661
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: It looks like that you dont have a docker-compose.yml file !?

Comment: Yes I hace docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

you may just need to check if you install sail correctly

check the documentation : [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail)

1- `composer require laravel/sail --dev`

2- `php artisan sail:install`  that should publish a `docker-compose.yml` in your **root DIR** that file it's like a **env** file for Docker

3- `./vendor/bin/sail up` this will run the App

note:-

after this steps if you don't saw `docker-compose.yml`
try to publish it manually